# Date comparison with Npgsql EF Core

Tags: date, npgsql, ef-core-3.1

I am trying to find records in a Postgresql table with a column of type Date using a simple equality. I am using DateTime properties (not noda)

I am sure that I am missing something very basic because I am not succeeding after trying many different ways.

The following code does not return any result even though the date is equal to Dates in the database:

```
var m = new Model {
   dateprop = default(DateTime)
}
var result = await context.Model
   .Where(a => a.dateprop == m.dateprop)
   .ToListAsync()
```

In the database, there are plenty of records with such date, 0001-01-01, in the column.

Besides, I have tried:

- .Where(a => a.dateprop == m.dateprop.Date)
- .Where(a => a.dateprop.Date == m.dateprop.Date)
- .Where(a => a.dateprop.Date == m.dateprop)
- .Where(a => a.dateprop.Equals( m.dateprop)) and all the varieties above

Then, if I get the query that EF produces for `.Where(a => a.dateprop.Date == m.dateprop.Date)` and run it from a SQL client, it works and returns all the records.

What is the correct way to define the Date equality condition in the where clause?

**Edit**
I have edited the question since it was misleading, my apologies. Originally, the code showed as:

```
var m = new Model {
       dateprop = DateTime.Parse("1970-01-01")
    }
    var result = await context.Model
       .Where(a => a.dateprop == m.dateprop)
       .ToListAsync()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following runnable code sample works. I'd double-check my database to see exactly what's in there and whether it corresponds to `default(DateTime)`, and if you're still convinced there's an issue, try tweaking the code below to make it appear.

```cs
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await using var ctx = new BlogContext();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureDeletedAsync();
        await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

        var m = new Model
        {
            DateProperty = default
        };
        var result = await ctx.Model
            .Where(a => a.DateProperty == m.DateProperty)
            .ToListAsync();

        Console.WriteLine($"Count: {result.Count}");
    }
}

public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Model> Model { get; set; }

    static ILoggerFactory ContextLoggerFactory
        => LoggerFactory.Create(b => b.AddConsole().AddFilter("", LogLevel.Information));

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder
            .UseNpgsql(@"Host=localhost;Username=test;Password=test")
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .UseLoggerFactory(ContextLoggerFactory);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        => modelBuilder.Entity<Model>().HasData(
            new Model { Id = -1, DateProperty = default });
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateProperty { get; set; }
}
```